# Python 3 can't run Pygame Windows

Tags: pygame, pycharm

I have found some questions similar to this one, but the platform was Ubuntu and I have Windows 7. I try to run Pygame on Python 3 and it does not work. When I try it on Python 2, it works perfectly. This is the problem I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Slava Sprogis/PycharmProjects/InventWithPython/Chapter1/HelloWorld.py", line 1, in <module>
import pygame
ImportError: No module named 'pygame'
```

I work in Pycharm.

Comment: You have to install pygame for Python 3 as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get Pygame for Python 3.
A bunch of Pygame downloads for Python 3.x can be found here: https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/downloads/

Make sure you're installing Pygame onto your Python 3 directory(should be `Python3(VERSION_HERE)`)

Also check if you have a `pygame` folder in your Python version's `include` folder.

If you have any more problems, just comment on this answer and I'll try to help.